# How do I make a list start at the same level than the text surrounding it (Without extra left space)?

Tags: lists, indentation, itemize

I want my list to begin straight at the left side of my page, without the usual space to the left (which is about the length of a paragraph tabulation). I tried setting parameters from inside the list to zero, but it doesn't seem to come from there.

Did I miss something? How can I achieve this?

I used the following test code, to no avail :

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\begin{itemize}
\item One.
\item Two.
\item Three.
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0in}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\listparindent}{0in}
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0.pt}
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{0in}
    \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
    \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}

\item Modified one.
\item Two.
\item Three.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `enumitem` package is best for adjusting list formatting.

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{leftmargin=*} % makes all itemize lists line up with the  surrounding text
```

or if you just want it for a single list:

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
\item ...
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Thanks, why doesn't the setlength command work? I noticed that it works for some parameters like itemsep.

Comment: itemize copies some of the values at the start to internal lengths. E.g. `\topsep` is used to calculate `\@topsep`. And this internal lengths are then later used. So changing \topsep after \begin{itemize} doesn't have an effect. (Changing before doesn't work because at the start of the list \topsep is setup to the default defined in \@listi.)