# How to align text and itemize in the starting with same margin?

Tags: margins, itemize

How can we align Text and itemize starting with same margin?

```
This is my first sentence.
. this is first bullet point line.
. this is second bullet point line.
```

Comment: An MWE is always nice, even if the question seems obvious.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8160/15925 help?

Comment: I would say, it is even a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the package `enumitem`. Then, you just add one line to your document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}
\item one
\item two
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

I also utilized `lipsum` for some blind text.

The output is:

[image: lists]