# Make list start at same line as its section

Tags: lists, margins, itemize, multicol, enumitem

I am trying to save space in my [CV](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/cv/), so now please see this picture of it:

[image]

Notice how Skills is aligned with its content, without leaving any blank line. However, Languages leaves too much empty space (like a blank line) and then continues. I would like it to be exactly as with Skills.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true ,urlcolor=blue,urlbordercolor={0 1 1}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{url}
\oddsidemargin -.5in
\evensidemargin -.5in
\textwidth=6.0in
\itemsep=0in
\parsep=0in
\topmargin=0in
\topskip=0in
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newcommand{\Myoops}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\section{\sc Languages}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
  \item English (C2)
  \item German (B1)
  \item Italian (A1)
  \item Greek (native)
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
```

Also notice that this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8160/how-do-i-make-a-list-start-at-the-same-level-than-the-text-surrounding-it-witho) did not solve the issue. I am also open in throwing away the list, as long as I can display my languages in one line fashion, while keeping them nicely separated.

Link to `res.cls` as requested: https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/cv-in-latex/

Comment: If this depends specifically on `res.cls`, would you mind including that code or posting a link to it? That is, does the problem still exist if you use a standard document class?

Comment: To having the reader focus on the part that *I think* generates the issue. I will post the `res.cls` now, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the `inline` option and `itemize*` instead of `itemize`

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{url}
\oddsidemargin -.5in
\evensidemargin -.5in
\textwidth=6.0in
\itemsep=0in
\parsep=0in
\topmargin=0in
\topskip=0in
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true ,urlcolor=blue,urlbordercolor={0 1 1}]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\Myoops}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\begin{document}
\section{\sc Languages}
  \begin{itemize*}[leftmargin=*,itemjoin={\quad}]
  \item English (C2)
  \item German (B1)
  \item Italian (A1)
  \item Greek (native)
\end{itemize*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Christian thanks! This is almost perfect, it worked. However, wouldn't it be nice to have some space between every item?

Comment: @gsamaras: Ah, yes: Use `itemjoin={\quad}`, for example (or two `\quad\quad`)

Comment: Hey Christian, sorry for jumping into this again but I decided I want to use that again, now for two list items per row, however, I cannot see where you specified that the list items were 4 in my question at that time. Should I ask a new question or it is easy?

Comment: @gsamaras: There's no such option as far as I know, but you can use a `\\\` after two items

Comment: That's a bit ugly, since the li's are not vertically aligned properly and the space between the two rows is too little. I went via this [solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194426/split-itemize-into-multiple-columns), thanks! :)

Comment: @gsamaras: Well, yes. It's another question anyway

Comment: You are right Christian, sorry, I went ahead and posted a new [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320818/make-two-columned-list-start-at-same-line-as-its-section).