# Make two-columned list start at same line as its section

Tags: lists, margins, enumerate, itemize, two-column

Following this: [Make list start at same line as its section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284994/make-list-start-at-same-line-as-its-section) I now have two columns, instead of four, but things don't work out, see for yourself (you can get `res` at [CV in Latex](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/cv-in-latex/)):

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

    Combine the good characteristics from both approaches; I want the first list to start at the same height as ``Languages".

    \section{\sc Languages}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
            \item English (C2)
            \item German (B1)
            \item Italian (A1)
            \item Greek (native)
        \end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}

    Other solution, which does that, but doesn't vertically align the li's and minimizes the space between the two lines, which is ugly.
    \section{\sc Languages}
    \begin{itemize*}[leftmargin=*,itemjoin={\quad}]
        \item English (C2)
        \item German (B1) \\   % I break the line here
        \item Italian (A1)
        \item Greek (native)
    \end{itemize*}
\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image]

Any idea on how to tackle this?

Comment: Perhaps the `tasks` package is much better here than `enumitem` for this particular setup!

Comment: What Bernard has done in his answer ;-)

Comment: OK thanks @ChristianHupfer (I managed to delete my comment by mistake before, I should get a badge about it... :) ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with `tasks`. If you want sections tobe in small caps, you can redefine `\sectionfont` in the preamble. Note the syntax `\sc`, `\bf`, `it` is deprecated and should be replaced with the switches `\scshape`, `\bfseries`, `\itshape` or the commands `\textsc{…}`, `\textbf{…}`, `\textit{…}`.

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
\def\sectionfont{\scshape}

 \usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

    Combine the good characteristics from both approaches; I want the first list to start at the same height as ``Languages".

    \section{Languages}
     \begin{tasks}[label = \textbullet,  after-item-skip = 0.5ex plus 0.5ex](2)
        \task English (C2)
        \task German (B1) %
        \task Italian (A1)
        \task Greek (native)
    \end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, well I won't break the line here. I did that in an attempt to find a solution. Still, the distance between the two rows is a bit greater than the one I get in the 1st list of my question, my I guess that's a fair trade-off!

Comment: The problem was just I left a \\  that you needed in your initial try. I removed it and changed a little the value of the  key  in charge of the inter-row skip, `after-item-skip`. The parameters are explained in § 4, pp.8-12 of the documentation. PLease see if my updated answer is OK. Καληνύχτα!

Comment: Thanks for that Bernard. However, in the updated answer I am having a hard time following the code, I mean I don't even see where is English, German, Italian and Greek even written.. :/ Καληνύχτα, I will check again later and try to understand. :)

Comment: You indeed can have a hard time: I  messed up with my clipboard manager. It's fixed now.

Comment: Bernard, oh it's a beauty, isn't it! Ευχαριστώ! I know it's night time for you, but I have posted a new [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320826/verb-illegal-in-command-argument-in-task), so tomorrow if you have time and joy, check it out.