# \verb illegal in command argument in task

Tags: verbatim, arguments, tasks

Following this: [Make two-columned list start at same line as its section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320818/make-two-columned-list-start-at-same-line-as-its-section), I did:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

    \section{Languages}
     \begin{tasks}[label = \textbullet](2)
        \task C{}\verb!++!.
        \task German (B1)
        \task Italian (A1)
        \task Greek (native)
    \end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

which results in the error:

```
./foo.tex:14: LaTeX Error: \verb illegal in command argument.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14     \end{tasks}

?
```

I read this: [How to put \verb command inside of \textbf{} block?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24574/how-to-put-verb-command-inside-of-textbf-block), but was still unable to apply the solution, I tried:

`\task \cprotect C{}\verb!++!.`

but that resulted in:

```
Runaway argument?
{\task }{,label = \textbullet }{2} \task 
./foo.tex:10: Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \tasks.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.10         \task \cprotect
                             C{}\verb!++!.
?
```

How to fix this?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4302/prettiest-way-to-typeset-c-cplusplus?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this:

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand\Cpp{C\Verb!++!}
```

But why not a simple  `C{}\texttt{++}`?